# Make all tuples with no more 1s than 0s

Tags: python, performance

I can make all n-tuples containing only 1s and 0s using  `A= list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n))` for example.  How can I efficiently make all tuples where there are no more 1s than 0s without creating `A` first and then deleting lots of tuples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete them on-the-fly, before you persist them in a list.

```py
A = [x for x in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n) if sum(x)*2<=n]
```

I doubt that generating them is the 'hard' part of your whole algorithm. So don't worry about the 2 x overhead for generating the unnecessary half of the tuples with more 1s.

Additionally, keep in mind that the list will take a huge amount of memory for large N. Maybe you could just use generators all the time.

*For the records:* My first attempt works only in python 2.x, for 3.x itertools.ifilter() simply becomes filter().

```
A = list(itertools.ifilter(
          lambda x:sum(x)*2<=n, 
          itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am in python 3 but I think I just replace itertools.ifilter with filter?

Comment: Yea, just replace it. 
I've added another version using list comprehension. Probably the most pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate(Tuple, n):
    if len(Tuple) == n:
        print Tuple
    else:   
        if Tuple.count(1) >= n / 2:     # If number of 1 is greater then n/2
            generate(Tuple + (0, ), n)  # then we can't append 1 to the tuple
        else:
            generate(Tuple + (1, ), n)
            generate(Tuple + (0, ), n)

if __name__ == '__main__':      
    n = 4
    generate((), n)
```